# git clone + install in Python

Tags: python, git, pip

Is there a one-liner shortcut for:

```
git clone https://github.com/user/mypythonmodule.git
cd mypythonmodule
python setup.py install
cd ..
```

like

```
git clone install https://github.com/user/mypythonmodule.git
```

or doesn't this exist?

Comment: git clone https://github.com/user/mypythonmodule.git && python mypythonmodule/setup.py install

Comment: install it using pypi : pip install mypythonmodule

Comment: @PeterClause: I tried but doesn't work because the current path won't be `mypythonmodule` with your solution

Comment: @ImanMirzadeh: such git projects are not always on Pypi

Comment: @Basj: yup ! but they usually are :D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you use pip it supports installing from git URLs.

From the [pip documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install.html#git)

"pip currently supports cloning over git, git+https and git+ssh"

So you would do

```
pip install git+https://github.com/user/mypythonmodule.git
```

Comment: Nice solution. I admit, that I first wanted to avoid asking target users to install `pip`, because on my Raspbian Wheezy : `apt-get install python-pip` installs pip + .... Python 2.6 on top of Python 2.7 ... :s ugly !

Comment: Is Python 2.7 default in Raspbian Jessie? Alternatively if you have a python 2.7 easy_install you could install pip using that rather than apt.

Comment: @StephenPaulger, does that really work without the `git+`prefix? For me it seems that it has to be `pip install git+https://github.com/user/mypythonmodule.git`